# twitter oauth with single-use access token

Tags: twitter, oauth

Is it possible to authenticate from a web page without any server-side 
program?  I would like to use javascript (and jsonp with query-string 
oauth, I am guessing) and hard code my access_token in a javascript 
variable. 
I know this would be a major security no-no.  I have no intention of 
putting the webpage on the internet. 
I simply would like to know if my intention is even possible.  It 
would be greatly appreciated if someone could put aside the security 
issue for a moment and answer my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do. You just need an OAuth 1.0 JS library to make authenticated request from JS. Note that you need to include both the access token and client credentials in the application - so it's double insecure.